# Asp.Net c# Interactivity In Windows Forms using onMouseMove Event to Highlight a data point in Charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, asp.net-charts

I have been working with charts in the Asp.Net framework and I found a nifty Interactivity I could add to the chart for each 'bar' of data in a bar chart. However no matter how I try to implement this from the msdn website found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456772.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) at **Interactivity in Windowms Forms**, I keep getting multiple errors with:

```
this.Chart1.MouseMove += new   System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Chart1_MouseMove);
```

as well as with

```
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e
```

What this is supposed to do is whenever you highlight over a bar in the bar chart the event should fire and change a few effects such as changing the color.

The link above will redirect you to the code however It it also here:

```
this.Chart1.MouseMove += new      System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Chart1_MouseMove);

private void Chart1_MouseMove(object sender,   System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{

   HitTestResult result = Chart1.HitTest( e.X, e.Y );

   // Reset Data Point Attributes
   foreach( DataPoint point in Chart1.Series[0].Points )
   {
       point.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Black;
       point.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.None;
       point.BorderWidth = 1;
   }

   // If the mouse if over a data point
   if(result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
   {
       // Find selected data point
      DataPoint point = Chart1.Series[0].Points[result.PointIndex];

      // Change the appearance of the data point
      point.BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;
      point.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.Percent25;
      point.BorderWidth = 2;
   }
   else
   {
       // Set default cursor
      this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
   }
}
```

The errors that show up are:

- Default (page) does not containe a definition for cursor and no extension... (Nothing to import shown by intellisense)
- Chart does not have a definition for MouseMove
- MouseEventHandler could not be found

I cannot find any information anywhere else on how to accomplish and or get this Microsoft event to work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer unfortionalty lies in your question:

> I have been working with charts in the Asp.Net framework...
>
> msdn website found here at Interactivity in Windowms Forms...

Windows Forms is not the same as ASP.net framework. The linked page is divided into 2 sections asp.net- and winForms chart interactivity.

Look at eh asp.net section and perhaps you can find some answer there